# Xcode "switch/case" statement - warning about break;

Tags: objective-c, xcode, switch-statement

What constantly happens to me is this, when I'm using Xcode with Objective-C:

I'll be writing a `switch`/`case` statement. Typically, to make sure statements are separated, the programmer must make sure there are `break;`s between `case`s.

I often forget to put the `break;` statement in, so instead of the device executing **only** the the desired `case`, the device executes the `case` and then the `case` after it. This happens on both a physical device (iPhone 6) and on every simulated device on iOS Simulator.

Here's what the syntax of the *failed* statement looks like, with `someInt` being a number that is either `0` or `1`:

```
switch (someInt)
{
    case 0:
    {
         // some statements to execute if "someInt" is 0
    }
    case 1:
    {
         // some statements to execute if "someInt" is 1
         break;
    }
}
```

**Note how, in `case 0:`, there is no `break;` statement.** This causes `case 0:` to execute *and then* `case 1` to execute, instead of just `case 0` to execute.

### Is there a way I can put a flag in Xcode so it warns me if I forget a `break;` statement?

I know many programmers have probably been confused for days, weeks on end, because of this problem.

Comment: I'm forced to admit that my personal solution was to avoid the use of switch statements in Objective-C. This is a reason to switch (pun intended) to Swift. Totally safe, usable switch statement. No break needed, no automatic fall-through.

Comment: The syntax of switch is a reason for moving from a dynamic typing programming language to a static typing programming language  …?

Comment: The static typing is another good reason of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that there is a compiler warning. This is, because "the programmer must make sure there are `break`s between cases." is not fully correct. The programmer must make sure that there are `break`s between the `case`s, *if he wants the code not to fall through*. (There are use cases for falling through.)

The background is that C was akin of replacement for assembler. In assembler you write a multi-selection with conditional jumps to the specific branch (`case`) and unconditionally jumps out of a branch (`break`), if you do not want to continue. (BTW: This is the reason for being `case`-branches no blocks, too.)

Of course, this is obsolete. You can simply use the automatic code generation of Xcode or replace switches with `if`-`else if`-`else` cascades.

Comment: I suppose there may be some uses for a `switch` statement to fall through, but, for me, it's not useful.

Comment: Yes, of course usually you want to exit after each case branch. This is, why the Xcode template contains breaks. It is an obsolete feature of C as I said.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is an implicit part of the C language (which underlies Objective C) and although more often than not, you don't want the fall through to the next case, for better or worse, this is the way the language is defined.

Swift, on the other hand, doesn't require an explicit break as cases do not fall through.

Clang does define a warning `-Wimplicit-fallthrough` which generates a warning in the situation you describe, however it doesn't seem to be supported in the Clang included with Xcode 6.3.2. I don't have Xcode 7 installed yet to check if this is still true in that version.

Comment: I don't have Xcode 7. My MacBook Air has a 128 GB hard drive, and, being a developer, I'm lucky to have maybe a GB or two free at a time.

Comment: Maybe I do not speak english well enough, but I think that it is a explicit (and intended) part of the C language.

Comment: Yes, that is what I said. Clang has an option to generate a warning in this situation but Apple have not implemented this, at least not in 6.3.2